# What kind of a question is this? Is it rhetorical? If so, what type of rhetorical?

Tags: questions

From Toni Morrison's Beloved:
"They beat you and you was pregnant?"

This is asked by Paul D in response to Sethe who describes that she was beaten when she was pregnant. Paul D knows the answer, this is more of an incredulous question, also angry, in disbelief... any particular way to classify it?

Comment: There is no auxiliary inversion here, or wh-question-word plus inversion (Were you beaten? / Have you any witnesses? Did you fight back? Where/When/Why ... did this take place? ...). "They beat you." is a declarative statement, and with the correct intonation "They beat you?" is a declarative question. Some might be tempted to double-punctuate here, adding an exclamation mark to the question mark.

Comment: I feel like I shouldn't be answering this.

Comment: The question mark is acting like musical notation.  And the musical notation of raising the voice at the end turns it into a question.  This usage makes an interrogative of rhetorical disbelief.

Answer (score 0):

It is erotesis - a type of rhetorical question that [conveys a passionate affirmation or denial](https://www.acethepresentation.com/rhetorical-questions/).

> Erotesis, which is also known as erotema, eperotesis and interrogation is another type of rhetorical question that conveys a strong or passionate affirmation or denial.

Or [said another way](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/erotesis):

> A manner of phrasing a question that presupposes an answer that is either a strong affirmative or, more often, a strong negative.

Comment: I took a look at the link and I’m not convinced OP’s question is erotesis based on the examples given.

Comment: I'm sorry you're not convinced. I am, though. :)

Comment: My take is that erotesis is “answering a question with another question”- one that has a presupposed answer.   Q: Do you want ice cream?  A: “Do birds live in trees?”   (Strong affirmative YES!)    OP’s question expressed incredulity but I see no erotesis.

Comment: The obvious answer is "YES," said through tears or with hurt defiance. Thus, it is erotesis.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstand.  The erotetic question ***IS*** the answer, it does not seek an answer.

Comment: Of course it doesn't seek an answer. It's a rhetorical question.

Comment: Then why did you say that the “obvious answer is “Yes” said through tears or with hurt defiance?

Comment: @Jim Your point is that when A said "Do birds live in trees?" those words amounted to the word "Yes" as a response to Q's earlier question, "Do you want ice cream?" I see that distinction, but the ice-cream-discussion is the only example in that category. In OP's Toni Morrison quotation and in the quotations of MLK and Burke, a single question implies its own firm answer, not the answer to another earlier question. They beat you? [Yes they did!] How can segregation exist in the true church? [Of course it cannot!]  Etc. So the link supports the classification of OP's example as erotesis. No?